# OpsWorks app domains not resolving after adding elastic ip

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, aws-opsworks

I have an issue that I have been trying to work out for a while now.  I am experimenting with AWS and thinking of moving sites over, but I can't get DNS to work with OpsWorks apps. I have a PHP / RDS stack that I have a few apps in.

These were working great except for the issue of OpsWorks instances having a dynamic DNS that changes upon instance reboot. I don't want to have to change my DNS records in Route53 every time that happens, so I implementated an EIP, registered it with the instance, and registered it with OpsWorks. I added rules to the policy that the EC2 uses for default VPC to accept incoming HTTP requests as well.

Now, when I add an A record to my DNS zone that points to the EIP, and add my domain in the OpsWorks app settings, my domain does not resolve in the browser. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

OpsWorks does very little to manage DNS externally. All DNS management should be done through Route53.

To start, make sure you have your nameserver (NS) record properly configured to reference your domain in your hosted zone, and also make sure that whatever DNS provider you're using (e.g. name.com, etc) is configured to point to those DNS servers.

Also, regarding this point:

> I don't want to have to change my DNS records in Route53 every time
>   that happens, so I implementated an EIP, registered it with the
>   instance, and registered it with OpsWorks.

You should really be using an elastic load balancer for this, not an elastic IP. You can associate an elastic load balancer with your OpsWorks stack so that any instances launched within the OpsWorks stack will be associated with that elastic load balancer. The additional benefit is that you can have multiple servers hosting your application as you scale.

Comment: Should I be using an elastic IP on the ELB?

Comment: No, the elastic IP has it's own DNS which you can map to your own using an A record.